# Cannot destroy Firebase connections making hot Lambda fail due to 'Firebase App name '[DEFAULT]' already exists'

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, aws-lambda

Been trying every approach I can think of for hours.

Basically I'm running an AWS Lambda function which does some work to my Firebase app in both a client and server role.

Being on Lambda, I need to be able to reverse the `firebase.initializeApp(config)` and `firebase.initializeApp(config, 'server')`. I've tried `firebase.app('server').delete()` but that doesn't seem to work.

Thanks in advance for any help.

To clarify, I can't just use the existing connection because the config may change.

Comment: Try `firebase.app("[DEFAULT]"). delete()`.

Comment: It's working for me in a Node process. I'm able to create and delete named apps. You could try calling `self.serverFirebase.delete()` instead of looking up the app using the name you specified in the `initializeApp` call.

Comment: thanks @cartant this resolves the surface of the issue, now i think it's I've created a new issue where the new connection is done inside the then() making it async so I need to move the main work to not start until after that work is done (in a separate file).

Comment: Yep, `delete` returns a Promise.

Comment: setImmediate(activate) fixed that issue - I was using naively using process.nextTick(activate). Submit your original comment as the answer (minus the rogue space) and I'll mark it as the answer. Thanks again @cartant

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Calls to `initializeApp` take an optional app name. If the app name is not specified, the name `[DEFAULT]` is used.

To uninitialize an app, you need to call `delete` on the app instance. The app instance is returned by the `initializeApp` call or can be obtained using the `app` function.

That is, you can initialize and uninitialize an app like this:

```
app = firebase.initializeApp(configuration);
app.delete();
```

Or like this:

```
firebase.initializeApp(configuration);
firebase.app('[DEFAULT]').delete();
```

Note that the `delete` function returns a promise that resolves when the app deletion is complete.

Answer (score 1):

`initializeApp` returns the initialized app.
You can do :

```js
const app = firebase.initializeApp(config);
//...
await app.delete();
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can also just initialise the Firebase instance outside of your handler function and pass it down. This prevents it from getting invoked multiple times.

Lambda likes to spin up one instance of a function, but continuously call its function handler, meaning code outside the handler is only executed once.

This can be applied to most anything that only lets you have one instance going.