# AWS lambda timeout on custom intents

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I am building an Amazon Alexa skill that gets data async from Google's Firebase.

When I run the Lambda function locally and call it from my Alexa skill all intents work as expected.

However when I zip up the files (not the folder) and move it to AWS lambda the function times out even thought the data has been received and the response object created as expected.

The built in intents are all working as expected too

My code is [on GitHub here](https://github.com/SSmale/TeaMaid)

[The error log and console.log outputs](https://gist.github.com/SSmale/08be2cfb5f93340a0f1a8ea3b5dff519)

I have tried to find any solutions via here and google but no luck. It could be that I have been searching the wrong things or this is a specific problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39436072/cannot-destroy-firebase-connections-making-hot-lambda-fail-due-to-firebase-app)

When using firebase with lambda it would appear that you need to initalize and then delete the instance for the response to be returned.

this is a code snippit that I got to work

```
const Alexa = require("ask-sdk");
const firebase = require("firebase");

var config = {
  ...
};

const GetOrderIntent = {
  canHandle(handlerInput) {
    const request = handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request;
    return (
      request.type === "IntentRequest" &&
      request.intent.name === "GetOrderIntent"
    );
  },
  async handle(handlerInput) {
    firebase.initializeApp(config);

    try {
      const store = await firebase
        .database()
        .ref(`teams/${team}`)
        .once("value");
      // ANY OTHER CODE HERE
   } catch (error) {
      // HANDLE ERROR
    }
    // CLOSE THE CONNECTION
    await firebase.app("[DEFAULT]").delete();
    return handlerInput.responseBuilder
      .speak(speechOutput)
      .withSimpleCard(SKILL_NAME, speechOutput)
      .getResponse();
  }
};
```

Comment: I don't know why I don't find documentation about this anywhere but this seems to fix the problem.
You can also do :

    `const app = firebase.initializeApp(config);
    /* ... */
    await app.delete();`